# c++ find similar files names

Tags: c++, find

I have a directory, contains files:

```
"bc[1]",
"bc[2]",
.
.
.
"abc[1]",
"abc[2]",
.
.
.
```

and some other files.

I would like to find files with name "bc", but not include "abc" files..
I have the following code, it listed all the "bc" and "abc" files.

```
f->cd("SomePath");
  TIter next(gDirectory->GetListOfKeys());
  TKey *key;
  while ((key = (TKey*)next()) ){
                if (key != nullptr){
                  string name = key->GetName();
                  if (name.find("bc")!= std::string::npos){
                    cout<<name<< endl;
                  }
                }
              }
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: `if (name.find("bc")==0)` - or did I miss the point.

Comment: What is `TIter` and `TKey` Please make a [mre]. Perhaps you want [`std::string::starts_with`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/starts_with)?